# Concatenate value of alt with text jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I seem to be close to an answer, but i keep getting "undefined" for the "alt" portion of the title. I'm trying to use the alt text and to add it to the text below in order to create a new title.

```
$("a").each (function () {
  $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("alt") + "Photograph of ");
});

<div id="example">
  <a href="images/Grass.jpg"><img src="images/Grass.jpg" alt="Grass" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("a").each (function () {
  $(this).attr("title", $(this).find('img').attr("alt") + "Photograph of ");
});
```

You were trying to get alt of `<img/`> tag

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm always close but not enough.